# client server socket based communication

Tags: java, java-me, sockets

I recently tested a socket based communication between a J2ME app and a local computer, the J2ME app was running on a emulator in NetBeans 6.7 and the server socket was also running on the same computer in Netbeans.
Now I would like to move the serversocket onto the internet and test the app first on the emulator and then on on actual mobile phone.
Is there anyway possible to put this socket onto a servlet on a webpage and then form a connection between that webpage and the local computer.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the topology you have in mind. A web page (pure HTML) is displayed in a brower, served by software running in the server. Where is ME in that relationship, and where do you intend the socket to be?

Comment: Actually, I was checking TCP socket connectivity between my J2ME app client and server which also was a java app running on localhost.
Now I just want to move the java app (server side) to a remote server on the internet so that I can check if my phone still successfully makes a socket connection with that computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "put" a socket servlet on a webserver, unless they have Java Server installed. Since this is hard to organize with most external webhosts, you'd have to instead configure your webserver to open a socket connection on a specified port number, I believe.

So later you should be able to contact the sever on a specified port, using its IP address or domain name. Like:

```
 100.200.300.400:965

         or

 mysubdomain.mydomain.com:965
```